# insert javascript array into another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Considering the following two arrays. How can I append array "lines" to array "array1". I have tried .push but it appends outside of the array. I have also tried .unshift which doesn't give me the wanted result.

```
array1 = [
  {
    "Activity #": "1111111",
    "Customer": "Last, First",
    "Tenure": "0 Year 2 Months",
    "Account #": "0000000"
  }];

lines = [
  {
    "Line #": "1",
    "Action Required": "New",
    "Status": "Closed",
    "Product Line": "test line1",
    "Product": "product1"
  },
  {
    "Line #": "2",
    "Action Required": "New",
    "Status": "Closed",
    "Product Line": "test line2",
    "Product": "product2"
  }];
```

I would like something like this.

```
my_array = [
{
    "Activity #": "1111111",
    "Customer": "Last, First",
    "Tenure": "0 Year 2 Months",
    "Account #": "0000000",
    "lines": [{
            "Line #": "1",
            "fields": "keys"
        },
        {
            "Line #": "2",
            "fields": "keys"
        }]
}]
```

With the mentioned used methods I get something like.

```
my_array = [
{
    "Activity #": "1111111",
    "Customer": "Last, First",
    "Tenure": "0 Year 2 Months",
    "Account #": "0000000"
}, [
    {
        "Line #": "1",
        "fields": "keys"
    }, {
        "Line #": "2",
        "fields": "keys"
    }]
];
```

Hope someone can help and my question is clear.

Comment: @Allan: As far as I can tell, this has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: Yep I confirm, nothing to do with json, shorcut mistake while editing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you want to add `lines` as property to object inside the array, so you'd have to do:

```
array1[0].lines = lines;
```

You haven't explained what exactly should happen if you have more elements in `array1`, so I cannot say anything about that.